# Logwatch: sendmail - sent/received?

Tags: sendmail, logwatch

Is it possible to get # of sent emails using logwatch? With our current setup I can see the number of received emails using 'logwatch --service sendmail -detail=11' but not the # sent.

I can probably parse this info out of the sendmail logs but it would make life much easier if logwatch can pull it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install [MIMEDefang](http://www.mimedefang.org), you can have [filter_recipient](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mimedefang-filter) log this information for you.

Comment: Looks cool. For now Im just parsing the Sendmail logs but this might be a better approach.